# Confusion about EOF and ÿ

Tags: c, eof

In my GCC on Windows, the value of `EOF` is `-1`. And I notice that the value of `'ÿ'` is also `-1`. So I did the following experiment and I'm totally confused of the results.

```
int main() {
    
    int a = 'ÿ';
    if (a == EOF) {
        putchar('a');
        putchar(a);
    }

    char b = 'ÿ';
    if (b == EOF) {
        putchar('b');
        putchar(b);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    int c;
    if ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar('c');
        putchar(c);
    }

    char d;
    if ((d = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar('d');
        putchar(d);
    }
}
```

The results are

```
aÿbÿ  // a == EOF b == EOF
ÿÿ    //My input for int c and char d
cÿ    // c != EOF
```

My questions are:
**1.** When I directly assign `'ÿ'` to a variable, no matter the type is int or char, it equals to `EOF`. But when I assign `'ÿ'` to `int c` from stdin, it turns out that `c` doesn't equal to `EOF`. What happened here?
**2.** How does the system distinguish between `'ÿ'` and `EOF` if there's a `'ÿ'` in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C program has an execution character set, and this determines how character literals are mapped to integer values.

It seems like your program is being compiled with iso-8859-1 as the execution character set. On my computer, the default for gcc is utf-8, where `'ÿ'` maps to the "multi-character constant" 50111. With iso-8859-1, gcc maps it to -1. I have to use the flag `-fexec-charset=iso-8859-1` to reproduce what you're seeing.

When you read from a file (or from stdin), you get whatever bytes the operating system gives you (interpreted as an unsigned character). The encoding of stdin and files is in general independent from the execution character set.

What you're observing is that the execution character set is iso-8859-1 mapped to the range -128 to 127 (rather than the usual 0 to 255), presumably with the rationale that `char` is signed on your compiler, so can represent every value in the execution character set. The encoding for stdin seems also to be iso-8859-1, except it uses the usual 0 to 255. In case (d) in your question, the value 255 is being assigned to a `char` (which is probably signed, from -128 to 127), and gcc is wrapping it.

Summary:

- (a) assigns -1 to `a`
- (b) assigns -1 to `b`
- (c) assigns 255 to `c`
- (d) converts 255 to a `char`, resulting in -1. This -1 is assigned to `d`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not sure about the meaning of "GCC is wrapping it", would you please explain it? Sorry, I'm newby to C.

Comment: From now on, my understanding is: `getchar()` returns an int value of the `unsigned character`.  when I do `char c = int i;`, if `i` is inclusively between **-128 - 127**, it is stored as a `signed char`. If `i` is between **128-255**, it will be converted to **-128-127** accordingly.

Comment: When I do `int i = some char c;`, based on my compiler, the mapping for `c` is **-128 - 127** instead of **0 - 255**.

Comment: For the second comment, should be **-128 to -1** accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[`'ÿ'`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00FF) is the character representation of number 255. Its value as char literal is `-1`.

Both `255` and `-1` have the same 8-bit representation (`11111111`), it depends if it is interpreted as a signed or unsigned value. `char` is signed, therefore its value as `char` is `-1`.

When it is assigned to a `char` variable it is stored as is.
When it is assigned to an `int` variable, the value is promoted to `int` and this does not change its value, it is only represented using more bits (4 bytes).

Incidentally `-1` is also the value of [`EOF`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) (but you should always use the constant `EOF` in the code and never rely on its numeric value).

---

[`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`; for `'ÿ'` it returns 255.

When it is assigned to an `int` the value is preserved.

When it is assigned to a `char`, the behaviour is undefined (because the possible range of values for a `char` variable is `-128`..`+127`).
It seems that your compiler chooses to store the rightmost 8 bits of `255` into the `char` variable and, due to the fact that `char` is signed, the value is interpreted as `-1`.

> How does the system distinguish between 'ÿ' and EOF if there's a 'ÿ' in the file?

[`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar), [`fgetc()`/`getc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) and other functions that read characters return `int`. This means they always return values between (and including) `0` and `255` when the succeed and `EOF` (that has a negative values) when there end of file is reached.

The value of `EOF` is negative, it cannot be confused with `'ÿ'`.

Comment: The assertion in this answer that the value of `EOF` “cannot be confused with `'ÿ'`” is contradicted by the reported behavior that `a == EOF` evaluates to true after `int a = 'ÿ';`.

Comment: The behavior of assigning an out-of-range value to a signed `char` is not undefined; it is implementation-defined. This answer contains a number of assertions that, while they may hold for common C implementations, are not required by the standard: `EOF` must be negative, but it is not necessarily −1. The representation of −1 is implementation-defined (from three choices). The number of bytes in an `int` is implementation-defined. The range of values returned by `fgetc` *et al* is not necessarily restricted to `EOF` and 0 to 255; it may be larger.